# Converting Sum's Values into Base 10

Tags: circuit-diagram

I am making a computer purely out of water. It's going well, but I have one problem. In the adders, where the sum exits, I just have water collected there. I don't know how to take the base two sum values and convert them back into base 10 and display it... any help would be great.

Comment: You need to connect the drain to earth.

Comment: Excuse me? I'm asking how to make a binary to BCD converter with water. I'm not sure how this can be done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using adders, do you mean AND gated.

[image][image]

No adders needed.